# StencilJS Rendering nested componentes

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs, stencil-component

I have created two web components that are nested together. The main problem that I am facing is when I try to render the child component, everything from the parent gets overlapped.
I think that the issue is that both parent component and child component are rendering `<slot/>`.
As you can see the parent component renders `<slot></slot>`. And the child component renders each of its slots by there name as well, the only "solution" that I found is to set shadow to true(`shadow:true`) in the child element, that way only the child `<slot/>` is shown and it doesn't get overlapped by the parent. But that is not working for me because inside my child component I would like to render another component, but since this is shadow DOM it does not show anything.
Any ideas?, thanks.

```html
<parent-component>
  <child-component>
    <div slot='title'>title</div>
    <div slot='subtitle'>subtitle</div>
  </child-component>
</parent-component>
```

```js
@Component({
  tag: 'child-component'
  shadow: false
})
export class ChildComponent{

  //my-logic

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <slot name='title'/>
        <slot name='subtitle'/>
        <external-component></external-component>
      </div>
    )}
  }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  tag: 'parent-component'
  shadow: false
})
export class ParentComponent{

  //my-logic

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    )}
  }
}
```

Comment: Which Stencil version are you using? There was a bug related to relocation of slot content in non-shadow components, I think it was fixed in Stencil 1.10 but can't remember exactly.

Comment: IMHO overlapping sounds like it might be a CSS problem, not JS.